# EventBus onEvent() not found after deployment

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, event-bus

I am developing in Java using Eclipse Luna SR1.  The app was tested successfully on a physical device.  However, after I deployed it, I received the `ClassNotFoundException` claiming there's no `onEvent()` method in my activity...but it's there.

Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: what do you mean under deploy? production build?

Comment: Yes, I generated an APK and sent it to GooglePlay as a beta.

Comment: did you use proguard?

Comment: Yes'ir...I sure did (don't like it very much though)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using proguard you need to add this to proguard.config

```
## GreenRobot EventBus specific rules ##
# https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md#proguard-configuration

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(***);
}

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends de.greenrobot.event.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    public <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}

# Don't warn for missing support classes
-dontwarn de.greenrobot.event.util.*$Support
-dontwarn de.greenrobot.event.util.*$SupportManagerFragment
```

official documentation https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md#proguard-configuration